# How to define custom capabilities in wordpress for custom plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, roles

I create own plugins with their own tables and actions. In these plugins I didn't make use of custom plugins.

However I want to define custom capabilities and roles. I want to base them on the action(url parameter).

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, you can create now user roles , users using coding. follow the codex.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Roles & Capabilities](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) in WordPress for a bit more information on what already exists and what they are used for.

Capabilities in WordPress are very basic because when you add a capability to a user, it doesn't actually do anything. It's when you add features that rely on the capability that it starts to have authority on the site.

The [`add_cap`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_role/add_cap/) documentation will give you some extra info, however this is how you can add a custom capability to the `author` role as an example:

```
$role = get_role( 'author' );
$role->add_cap( 'my_custom_cap' );
```

That's all there is to it. To remove a capability, use `remove_cap` instead of the `add_cap` above and it'll remove it properly from the role for you.

Comment: I already read these documentations. I have seen you have to map the capability with the exist capabilities of wordpress. I don't want that. I want to create own capabilites based on action/functions I have created/defined in my plugin. Could you please provide an example

Comment: I don't understand, that is how you create your own capabilities. Do you mean creating new user roles? That is done in much the same way as capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the other answers, I think what you wanna do is to "hook" your custom capability with some actions performed by the user. Example: you create and assign a new capability: "create_events", so your user will be able to create events.

You can create all logic in order to create Events and write a simple check on the user's capability to allow this actions or not. This is useful if you want to show some data or not.

Example:

```html
if (current_user_can("create_events")){
  
  //Do something

}
```